# Can elves have ADHD?

Tags: dnd-5e, elf

I know its a strange question but it would work great with my wood elf character. His playstyle is basically dance in and out of combat while his backstory is getting his sister killed by running around treetops.

Comment: The answer to this question is setting-dependant, and therefore subjective. (It depends on the answer to the question "does ADHD exist in such-and-such a setting?" which you'd have to ask your GM.)

Answer (score 4):

How you construct your character's background and personality (including any behaviors that might in the real world be classified as something like ADHD) is up to you, and to a slightly lesser extent your DM and the other players at your table. There's nothing in the actual rules of the game that specify how such things would work, so the details are between you and the other people at your table.